# C# Winforms "Projection Matrix" for printing

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have a UserControl that is `override Paint()` with my own drawings. I want to allow the user to print it.

Since I have already spent so much time writing a `public void Draw(Graphics e)` I was hoping to reuse this method and just passing the `PrintEventArgs.Graphics`. I realised that it's not so simple. I even have to page it myself.

Is there something like an OpenGL "Projection Matrix" I can use so as to calculate the "best fit" or "100% scale" kind of print features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Graphics object has a Transform property of type Matrix, which can be used to scale, rotate, etc. the drawn graphics in much the same way that OpenGL matrices are.

Answer (score 0):

I would move the user drawing into a separate method like this:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        Rectangle client=new Rectangle(0, 0, ClientSize.Width-1, ClientSize.Height-1);
        Render(e.Graphics, client);
    }

    public void Render(Graphics g, Rectangle client)
    {
        g.DrawEllipse(Pens.Blue, client); //test draw
        //...
    }
```

and then call it from the print document:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PrintPreviewDialog dlg=new PrintPreviewDialog();
        PrintDocument doc=new PrintDocument();

        doc.PrintPage+=(s, pe) =>
        {
            userControl11.Render(pe.Graphics, pe.PageBounds); // user drawing
            pe.HasMorePages=false;                
        };
        doc.EndPrint+=(s, pe) => { dlg.Activate(); };
        dlg.Document=doc;
        dlg.Show();            
    }
```

with the result:
[image: Screnshot]

**EDIT 1**
To keep the same number of pixels in the printout then modify the printing routine to:

```
        doc.PrintPage+=(s, pe) =>
        {
            Rectangle client = new Rectangle(
                pe.PageBounds.Left, 
                pe.PageBounds.Top,
                userControl11.ClientSize.Width-1,
                userControl11.ClientSize.Height-1 );
            userControl11.Render(pe.Graphics, client);
            pe.HasMorePages=false;                
        };
```

Comment: How would you extend this to draw multiple circles e.g. the Olympic logo?

Comment: @Jake: It is all in the `public void Render(Graphics g, Rectangle client)` method. You got to add all the `g.DrawEllipse()` command you want in there. If you want to know details suggest you create a new question on how to draw 5 circles in a user control or something.